# Using v-model inside nested v-for

Tags: vue.js, nested, carousel, quasar-framework, v-model

I am trying to use multiple carousel components inside card components with nested v-for loops but I’m having trouble figuring out the correct way to assign the carousel v-model so that it’s unique and doesn’t update all the carousels when the slide is changed which is what I currently have,
Here is the code I have so far:

```
<q-card
    v-for="(item, index) in inventory"
    :key="index"
    style="width: 20rem;"
  >
    <q-card-section
      class="q-pa-none text-white"
    >
      <q-carousel
        animated
        arrows
        navigation
        infinite
        style="height: 15rem;"
        v-model="slide" // What should this be assigned so that
      >
        <q-carousel-slide
          v-for="(image, index) in item.images"
          :key="index"
          :name="index" //It works with the slide name and only updates the respective q-carousel
          :img-src="image.url"
        >
        </q-carousel-slide>
      </q-carousel>
    </q-card-section>
  </q-card>
```

`slide` is simply a data prop assigned to 0, this works but when I change the slide of one carousel all of the carousels change too.
Hopefully this makes sense, It’s a bit hard for me to explain it but let me know anything that needs clarification

Edit: Dropped the code in codepen here is the link: https://codepen.io/launchit-studio/pen/jOVrKzQ
The issue I am having is that the v-model affects all of the carousel slides not just the one that is clicked. I understand this is because the slide prop is shared by all the carousels but I am not sure of what to use in order for it to be 'independent'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a single model `slide` for all the slides, use an array of models.  (An object would work too).

```js
data() {
  return {
    slide: 1,   ❌
    activeSlides: []  ✅
  }
}
```

The index of the carousel in the `v-for` will also be used as the index in the array:

```html
<q-carousel
  animated
  arrows
  navigation
  infinite
  style="height: 15rem;"
  v-model="activeSlides[index]"
>
```

Since each carousel's model needs to start at `1`, you can initialize `activeSlides` accordingly:

```js
created() {
  const numCarousels = this.inventory.length;
  this.activeSlides = Array(numCarousels).fill(1);
},
```

Here is the [updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/sh0ber/pen/PobzBPd).